# How can I display a single image in each row in xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning about listView in Xamarin Forms, and I want to use images, but I only want to display one image per row, but when I run my code, it displays all images at the same time. I have attached my code, so could you please help me how I can fix it

```
public class image: ViewCell
{
    public image()
    {
        var image = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image1.png"),
            HeightRequest = 50,
        };
        var image1 = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image2.png"),
            HeightRequest = 50,
        };
        var image2 = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image3.jpg"),
            HeightRequest = 50,
        };



        var stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 5, 5, 5),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = {
                image, image1, image2,
                new Label { Text = "images", VerticalOptions = 
                LayoutOptions.Center }
            }
        };

        View = stackLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe best first go through https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithListview/ because your list item template also contains all 3 images in a stacklayout and in the end you state that is not what you want.

Comment: I guess the best choice for you is to change to use a `CarouselView` component. Google it and see if it fits for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give stacklayout orientation as vertical or create a Grid with three rows & assign each image to one row.